# How to open a new activity when recycler view with search filter from hain file suggested some text is clicked in android studio

Tags: android-studio, search, view, android-recyclerview

I want to open a new activity when search filter is clicked in recycler view of android studio.
An open source code may be found here that is given below. It has json file from where we can fetch the search filter item.
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Please tell me the code that how we can get to new activity such as hello.xml when hello is being clicked in search filter item.

In my opinion the code should be here in mainactivity.java..

```
         @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Contact contact) {
String type = contact.getClass().getName();
            if (type.startsWith("Tom")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (type.startsWith("")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hello.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Please help to put my code instead of toast.

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onContactSelected(Contact contact) {

  //  TextView name = (TextView) Contact;

    if ( contact.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Tom Hardy"))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hello.class));
        finish();
    }
    else{

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " no activity "+contact.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}